# propiedades de arreglo de objetos

Tags: javascript, array

Gracias por leer el post y darme una mano,estoy practicando con algunos ejercicios, tengo un arreglo el cual paso como parametro a una funcion junto con un string esto deberia retornarme un nuevo arreglo de objetos, teniendo como parametro el string que pase como parametro:

Se me ocurre que deberia recorrer el arreglo y con una condicion verificar si hay una propiedad igual al string que me pasan como parametro, pero no se como poner el codigo.

```
let arreglo = [{ name: "lucas", edad: 20 }, { name: "santi", edad: 22 }]

    function oneProperty(arreglo, string) {
      
      }

oneProperty(arreglo,'name');
oneProperty(arreglo, “edad”) // [ { edad: 20 }, { edad: 22 } ]
oneProperty(arreglo, “name”) // [ { name: “lucas”}, { name: “santi” } ]
```

Comment: Considera leer [ask] y de paso hacer el [tour], tu pregunta puede quedar cerrada pues solo expone el enunciado de un trabajo pero no así lo que has intentado al momento, sugiero edites y le muestres a la comunidad lo que hayas tratado (*aún cuando no funcione*), de esa manera tendrán un punto de partida para ayudarte

Comment: ok, entendido... gracias¡

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que yo te recomendaría sería hacer un map para recorrer el objeto completo, y así ir haciendo "push" (es decir agregando) un objeto con la propiedad que pasaste como parámetro en cada vuelta:

```js
let arreglo = [{ name: "lucas", edad: 20 }, { name: "santi", edad: 22 }]

    function oneProperty(arreglo, string) {
      const mappedProperty = [] 
      // Primero creas un Array vacio para poder hacer push de los resultados.
      /* Luego recorres el array completo con map y haces push de un objeto en cada vuelta, donde el nombre de la propiedad va a ser el "string" que pasaste y el valor va a ser como si accedieras a tu objeto.string */
      arreglo.map(prop => mappedProperty.push(
        {[string]: prop[string]} 
        )
      )
      return mappedProperty
     }

console.log(oneProperty(arreglo,'name'));
console.log(oneProperty(arreglo, 'edad')) // [ { edad: 20 }, { edad: 22 } ]
```

Cualquier otra duda estaré atento, saludos!

Comment: la notación de corchetes es para hacer referencia a la variable? [string]

Comment: Utilizar Corchetes es la manera de denotar que la key (el nombre) de la propiedad es una variable, ya que si por ejemplo solo usas "string" (sin los corchetes), va a tomar la palabra "string" como Key y te va a quedar {string: 22}